# Passing objects vs. Passing references/pointers?

Tags: c++, oop

So, as we're all hopefully aware, in Object-oriented programming when the occasion comes when you need somehow access an instance of a class in another class's method, you turn to passing that instance through arguments.

I'm curious, what's the difference in terms of good practice / less prone to breaking things when it comes to either passing an Object, or a Pointer to that object?

Comment: The two do different things, so you cannot ask which one is preferable. Use the one that solves your problem.

Comment: Your question is similar to: I want to travel. Should I go by train or plane. Well, where are you going? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get into the habit of passing objects by reference.

```
void DoStuff(const vector<int>& values)
```

If you need to modify the original object, omit the `const` qualifier.

```
void DoStuff(vector<int>& values)
```

If you want to be able to accept an empty/nothing answer, pass it by pointer.

```
void DoStuff(vector<int>* values)
```

If you want to do stuff to a local copy, pass it by value.

```
void DoStuff(vector<int> values)
```

Problems will only really pop up when you introduce tons of concurrency. By that time, you will know enough to know when to not use certain passing techniques.

Comment: Most complete answer yet, could you add that passing by value uses a copy constructor (and example of a signature).

Answer (score 1):

I choose `const` reference as a default. Of course, non-`const` if you must mutate the object for the client. Deviation from using references is rarely required.

Pointers are not very C++ - like, since references are available. References are nice because they are forbidden to refer to nothing. *Update:* To clarify, proper containers for types and arrays are preferred, but for some internal implementations, you will need to pass a pointer.

Objects/values, are completely different in semantics. If I need a copy, I will typically just create it inside the function where needed:

```
void method(const std::string& str) {
  std::string myCopy(str);
  ...
```

Comment: I disagree with pointers somehow being detrimental to C++ practices, but I agree with passing constant references. It is the best habit to maintain.

Comment: @Justin If you're going to make a copy anyway, why not pass by value? See for example http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw For pointers and arrays: I use container types. For "Optional Parameters": I tend to offer two publicly visible calls -- these calls may call a private implementation which utilizes the optional parameter. When pointer parameters are generally reserved for "really internal" implementation details, it adds a lot of safety and improves readability (I find). However, there are of course people who have other preferences.

Comment: @Justin I definitely agree with using classes/wrappers to protect the usages. Pointers are like lepers out in public and need to be kept in dark caves (namely private class implementations). XD

Comment: @juanchopanza given the example I posted, what benefit would passing by value provide? the effect it would have in this scenario is PBV would lead to code bloat, as well as unnecessary copying+allocations (in some cases). also see dialog starting here: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/comment-page-1/#comment-1889

Answer (score 1):

Pass a pointer to the object if you want to be able to indicate nonexistence (by passing a NULL).

Try not to pass by value for objects, as that invokes a copy constructor to create a local version of the object within the scope of the call function. Instead, pass by reference. However, there are two modes here. In order to get the exact same effective behavior of passing by value (immutable "copy") without the overhead, pass by const reference. If you feel you will need to alter the passed object, pass by (non-const) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's really no good reason for passing a pointer to an object, unless you want to somehow indicate that no object exists.

If you want to change the object, pass a reference to it. If you want to protect it from change within the function, pass it by value or at least const reference.

Some people pass by reference for the speed improvements (passing only an address of a large structure rather than the structure itself for example) but I don't agree with that. In most cases, I'd prefer my software to be safe than fast, a corollary of the saying: "you can't get any less optimised than *wrong".* :-)

Comment: This is why it is common practice to pass it as a constant reference. Then you are safe AND fast! :D

Answer (score 0):

In fact what you can pass to a method is a pointer to object, a reference to the object and a copy of the object and all of these can also be constant. Depending on your needs you should choose the one that best suits your needs.

First descision you can make is whether the thing you pass should be able to change in your method or not. If you do not intend to change it then a const reference in probably the best alternative(by not changing I also mean you do not intend to call any non-const methods of that object). What are the advantages to that? You safe time for compying the object and also the method signature itself will say "I will not change that parameter".

If you have to change this object you can pass either a reference or a pointer to it. It is not very obligatory to choose just one of these options so you can go for either. The only difference I can think of is that pointer can be NULL(i.e. not pointing to any object at all) while a reference is always pointing to an existent object.

If what you need in your method is a copy of your object, then what you should pass a copy of the object(not a reference and not a pointer). For instance if your method looks like

```
void Foo(const A& a) {
  A temp = a;
}
```

Then that is a clear indication that passing a copy is a better alternative.

Hope this makes things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Object-oriented programming is about polymorphism, Liskov Substitution Principle, old code calling new code, you name it. Pass a concrete (derived) object to a routine that works with more abstract (base) objects. If you are not doing that, you are not doing OOP.

This is only achievable when passing references or pointers. Passing by value is best reserved for, um, values.

It is useful to distinguish between values and objects. Values are always concrete, there's no polymorphism. They are often immutable. 5 is 5 and "abc" is "abc". You can pass them by value *or* by (const) reference.

Objects are always abstract to some degree. Given an object, one can almost always refine it to a more concrete object. A RectangularArea could be a Drawable which could be a Window which could be a ToplevelWindow which could be a ManagedWindow which could be... These *must* be passed by reference.

Pointers are a wholly separate can of worms. In my experience, naked pointers are best avoided. Use a smart pointer *that cannot be NULL*. If you need an optional argument, use an explicit `optional` class template such as `boost::optional`.

Comment: +1 for recommending `boost::optional` instead of using raw pointers.

Comment: which smart pointer "that cannot be NULL" would you recommend. As far as I know, all boost smart pointers are allowed to be empty.

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer. Some of it is (partially informed) opinion, other parts are plain mysterious -- to what extents are objects "always abstract"? You may well argue that C++ objects *are* values, in the sense that the value of an object is the object itself. This notion is ubiquitous both in the written  standard and in the naming of the library (e.g. `declval`).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: this is all my own personal, barely informed opinion, acquired through my limited experience with OOP. The terminology is largely my own too, it does not follow any language standard because it is meant to be language-agnostic. If you disagree, by all means don't hesitate to downvote.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: what does it mean that objects are abstract? First of all objects are OOP objects, not C++ objects (which are just regions of memory). When doing OOD one does not thing about things like passing by pointer/reference, we're on a different level of abstraction. We have objects with such-and-such behaviour. What I mean is that they always can be wider (mode derived, more defined, more concrete, you name it) than interfaces we work with.